# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered React Native Error

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler, invariants

I was working on a React Native Project with a team and I suddenly got this error. Not sure if it helps but I did get it after I used expo to install the BarCodeScanner API from expo. But this hasn't occurred before whenever I installed an Expo API, and even after rolling back the changes the problem has persisted. I've tried other methods like closing everything and turning it back on but it doesn't change anything and I've still gotten this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T14J6.png)

Comment: hi there! try changing the react-native version in your package.json to `https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz` and then run `npm install` or `yarn` again. now when you start your application you should get a more useful red screen error, and a warning in your logs that will direct you to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application

Comment: Thanks @brentvatne for that, it gave a more clear error message now I'm just confused on how to fix it, the error is `Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider` any chance you would now how to fix that as well?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, I installed the `react-native-safe-area-context` again and it worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the solution.

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```